# Bare-metal Loader - Send .elf binary to other processor through shared memory and execute

Tags: c, linux, elf, bare-metal

Setup:
One ARM-CPU (A9) running busybox-Linux. This one talks to the network and gets a precompiled statically linked elf.
Second CPU runs bare-metal application. I have newlib on that one and the whole "OS" sits in memory just executing that one basic program.
Both share OCM.

I have succeeded in making the two processors "talk". I can write hex-values into memory from linux, the other processor reads it and vice-versa.
Now I'd like to parse the aforementioned elf, send it to OCM, make the bare-metal read it into it's memory, set the program counter via asm and execute said elf (could use a .o file as well).
I got stuck at parsing the elf already...

```
#include <sys/types.h>                                                                                                                    
#include <sys/stat.h>                                                                                                                     
#include <fcntl.h>                                                                                                                        
#include <byteswap.h>                                                                                                                     
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                                                       
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                       
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                        
#include <stdint.h>                                                                                                                       
#include <errno.h>                                                                                                                        
#include <sys/mman.h>                                                                                                                     

#define PAGE_SIZE ((size_t)getpagesize())                                                                                                 
#define PAGE_MASK ((uint64_t)(long)~(PAGE_SIZE - 1))                                                                                      

const unsigned int COMM_RX_DATA  = 0xFFFF900c;                                                                                            

int main(int argc, char **argv){                                                                                                          

    int     fd;                                                                                                                           
    int cached = 0;                                                                                                                       
    unsigned char* c;                                                                                                                     
    //uint32_t value;                                                                                                                     
    unsigned char value;                                                                                                                  
    uint64_t offset = COMM_RX_DATA;                                                                                                       
    uint64_t base;                                                                                                                        
    volatile uint8_t *mm;                                                                                                                 


    fprintf(stderr, "Nr. 0\n");                                                                                                           

    FILE* f_read;                                                                                                                         

    if ((argc != 1) && (argc != 2)) {                                                                                                     
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s  ELF_NAME\n", argv[0]);                                                                                
        return 1;                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                     

  fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);//|(!cached ? O_SYNC : 0));                                                                               
    if (fd < 0) {                                                                                                                         
        fprintf(stderr, "open(/dev/mem) failed (%d)\n", errno);                                                                           
        return 1;                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                     


    f_read = fopen(argv[1], "rb");                                                                                                        
    if(!f_read){                                                                                                                          
        fprintf(stderr, "read failed");                                                                                                   
        return 1;                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                     

    else {                                                                                                                                
        printf("Nr. 1\n");                                                                                                                
        base = offset & PAGE_MASK;                                                                                                        
        offset &= ~PAGE_MASK;                                                                                                             

        mm = mmap(NULL, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, base);                                                         

        fseek(f_read, 0, SEEK_END);                                                                                                       
        int size = ftell(f_read);                                                                                                         
        fseek(f_read, 0, SEEK_SET); //Reset stream                                                                                        
        c = malloc(size);                                                                                                                 
        //malloc error checking!                                                                                                          

        while (fgets(c, size, f_read) != NULL ){ //tried fgetc but segfaults                                                              
            //tmp-output to stdout                                                                                                        
            puts(c);                                                                                                                      
            value = c;//strtoull((char*)c, NULL, 0);                                                                                      
            printf("Writing %d to %d", (int)value, (int)(mm + offset));                                                                   
            *(volatile uint32_t *)(mm + offset) = value;                                                                                  
            printf("size: %d , value = %s\n", size, value);                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                                 

    }                                                                                                                                     
    munmap((void *)mm, PAGE_SIZE);                                                                                                        
    fclose(f_read);                                                                                                                       

    return 0;                                                                                                                             
}
```

_asm-idea.S:

```
ExecuteR0:
        mov  lr, r0 /* move the destination address into link register */

        mcr  15,0,r0,cr7,cr5,0      /* Invalidate Instruction cache */
        mcr  15,0,r0,cr7,cr5,6      /* Invalidate branch predictor array */

        dsb
        isb                 /* make sure it completes */

    ldr r4, =0
        mcr  15,0,r4,cr1,cr0,0      /* disable the ICache and MMU */

        isb                 /* make sure it completes */


        bx      lr  /* force the switch, destination should have been in r0 */
```

Help me mighty SO you're my only hope.

Comment: Could you elaborate your initial situition a little bit more? How did you execute the bare metal .elf on the second core? What are your snippets supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Have you thought about having the ELF include code to copy part of itself?  Then you get to take advantage of Linux's ELF program loader.  Note that `.data`, `.bss`, and `.text` are not contiguous, though.  So you need to copy all three separately.